# How do I share POJOs without mapping?

Tags: java, spring, orm

We are developing a webapp (client) with a RESTful API (server). Both projects uses the same domain so I created 3rd project containing all the POJOs so I can share it with my team.

The issue is that on the server side, I'm mapping these POJOs so I can persist them to data base easily.

```
@Document(collection="companies")
public class Company {

    @Id
    private final String nif;
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String name;
```

So how I could share the domain without my team to be aware that I'm mapping the POJOs and beside of saving the extra dependencies.

Comment: Use DTOs to decouple the data transfer between client and server from your entity model

Comment: Deleting my answer since there is a misunderstanding in the definition of entity/model/dto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is exactly what @dunni has pointed: using DTOs to decouple from entities + [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) (credit to @dimitrisli).

So my shared POJOs become DTOs(with no annotations) and on the server side I will use entities (pojos with annotations). Using MapStruct to convert from Dto to entity and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with spring but other frameworks allow you to use mixins. This will allow you to override or add annotations to your pojo at boot.

This will allow you to distribute just the pojo and then use mixins on your server to apply the annotations